# php - Dynamic array element value using regular expression result

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Using PHP, I have a `foreach` loop that loops through an associative array and echoes a specific element's value depending on the results of a regular expression `preg_match_all` like so:

```
$dictionary = array(
    '/red/' => 'cherry',
    '/green/' => 'apple',
    '/(brown|yellow)/' => 'banana',
    '/(orange|purple)/' => 'I like the '
    );

$input = $_POST['color'];

foreach ($dictionary as $pattern => $output) {
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $results)) {
        $matched_word = $results[1][0];
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same result, but also be able to echo `$matched_word` by referencing it in the original array (`$dictionary`)?

So if `$input` is ***"a brown fruit"***, that would mean `$matched_word` is *"brown"*; and if `$input` is ***"that yellow thing"*** then `$matched_word` would be *"yellow"*. 
Then I want to be able to change the array value like so:

```
...
    '/(brown|yellow)/' => 'banana is ' . $matched_word,
    '/(orange|purple)/' => 'I like the ' . $matched_word
...
```

But in this case `$matched_word` would appear non-existent. How can I achieve the same effect without completely rewriting the logic?

**EDIT:** Added some clarifications to code - regex patterns and outputs may be completely different.

Comment: What do you mean "echo by referencing"? How about `echo "$result is $matched_word"` in the loop?

Comment: erm, if you're matching  `/red/`, the `$matches` array won't have a key `1`, so `$results[1][0]` will issue a notice. Either way, what you want is: `$matched_word = array_pop($results); echo $output, ' is ', $matched_wourd[0];`. Easy

Comment: Exactly, some of the patterns yield more results than others, which is why I don't want to echo `$matched_word` inside the loop. Also, in some cases I want to print *'banana is (WORD)'*, whereas in other cases I want to echo just *'apple'*. "echo by referencing" is probably technically meaningless, I wasn't quite sure how to say it; the second code block is what I mean when I say "echo by referencing". I hope I'm being clear.

Comment: @Jason: and why wouldn't you be able to do that with `if ($output === 'banana') echo $output, ' is ', $matchedWord; else echo $output;`?

Comment: I want the loop to be as generic as possible, so anything specific to the "dictionary" remains in the array. But - I think I may be able to do something along those lines: Array element values which make use of regex matches will begin with some "magic word", and replacement dummies, like so: `if ( substr($output, 0, 5) == 'MAGIC' ) { $output = substr($output, 5, strlen($output)-1); echo str_replace('REPLACEME', $matched_word, $output); } else { echo $output; }`. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
...
    '/(brown|yellow)/' => 'banana is $matched_word',
    '/(orange|purple)/' => 'I like the $matched_word'
...
```

and then

```
        eval("echo \"$output\";");
```